# AdminLTE-3 activate a side navbar

Tags: php, html, css, adminlte

I am trying to use AdminLTE3 as admin panel in laravel and I have nav-item links which doesn't activate when I click them. I don't know how to fix this. I used the starter.html from adminLTE3 and I have all the required assets for adminLTE3 but my nav-item links are not activated, How can I fix this, I would really appreciate for any help. my side bar code is :

```
<nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
            <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="nav-icon fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                <p>
                    Dashboard
                    <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                </p>
                </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('home')}}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fab fa-elementor nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Main</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
              <p>
                Posts
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('posts.index')}}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
                  <p>All Posts</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-strikethrough"></i>
              <p>
                Services
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('services.index')}}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-asterisk nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>All Service</p>
                </a>
              </li>

            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('gallery.index')}}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="nav-icon fa fa-th"></i>
                  <p>
                    Galleries
                  </p>
                </a>
            </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{route('logout')}}" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-code"></i>

              <p>
                Logout
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

I tried the suggestion provided by kapitan

```
nav-link {{ Route::current()->getName() == 'posts.index' ? 'active' : '' }}
```

but problem is when I click any nav-item it hides like this

[image]

when I click the service drop down then it shows like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity sake:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link {{ Route::current()->getName() == 'my.route.name' ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

As you can see, this is a long cut method, you can improve this further. But this is a good starting point for you.

**UPDATE:**

Untested, but can you please try this:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link {{ Request::is('my/url','my/url/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<li class="nav-item has-treeview {{ Request::is('my/url','my/url/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">
    <i class="nav-icon fa fa-strikethrough"></i>
    <p>
      Services
      <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-treeview {{ Request::path() == 'my/url/here' ? 'menu-open' : '' }}">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="{{route('services.index')}}" class="nav-link {{ Request::is('my/url/here') ? 'active' : '' }}">
          <i class="fa fa-asterisk nav-icon"></i>
        <p>All Service</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: hi thankyou for your answer, i am getting the following issue i have updated the post if you have any idea please help

Comment: first suggestion and second update is same, both sets the <a> tag as active color only but doesn't stay active like in pic above

Comment: last try, please check the UPDATE2